# Do religious Orthodox Jews wish non-Jews ‘Happy holidays’?

Tags: gentiles, non-jewish-holidays

I have seen various opinions online and on this website. But I am looking for an Orthodox perspective. Do Torah observant Jews ever wish: "Happy holidays" during Christmas, New Year, Easter, Ramadan, Eid, and so on to non-Jews? Does Orthodox Halacha permit this?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12804/27180

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Oraly and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!